# How do I Turbo Boost in Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, turbo-boost

I have a 2010 Macbook Pro with Intel Core 2 Duo and I usually use it for gaming. I wanted to Turbo Boost it but how do I do that?

Comment: @allan's answer is correct. Also, turbo boost is not available for core2 processors. If you meant overclocking - there is no reliable solution that I would recommend.

Comment: Agree on both counts (you cannot affect TB and overclocking impractical). Your best approach to 'boost' this Macbook is to replace the HDD with a solid state drive and put your OS and applications on this. Then max out the Ram. This will help although beyond this you will still be limited by the processor and GPU which are not upgradeable. If you want a cheap gaming Mac buy a used MacPro Xeon tower, add an SSD and 32GB server Ram, 1.5 GB graphics card, upgrade the fans - 27" HP monitor.

Comment: That should be a good idea! Thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You can't.**

It's activated dynamically based on the workload.  There's nothing you can enable that turns on Turbo Boost.

From Intel's Website for the [i7-640M Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/49666/Intel-Core-i7-640M-Processor-4M-Cache-2_80-GHz) found in the 17" Mid 2010 MacBook Pro:

> Intel® Turbo Boost Technology dynamically increases the processor's
>   frequency as needed by taking advantage of thermal and power headroom
>   to give you a burst of speed when you need it, and increased energy
>   efficiency when you don’t.

This applies to **all** computers with Intel processors with the Turbo Boost technology, not just MacBooks.

[Intel's Turbo Boost Technology](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html) Note:

> Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 allows the processor to operate at a
>   power level that is higher than its TDP configuration and data sheet
>   specified power for short durations to maximize performance.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that it gains the additional thermal overhead by spooling down the other cores - the Turbo frequency is a single core speed. If you're running a workload that takes advantage of multiple cores simultaneously (video editing is the most common), it will not go into boost mode.